# Shared array in Julia reacts strangely to println

Tags: arrays, loops, parallel-processing, julia

My Julia version is 1.0.1 running on Windows 10.

I do some operations on a 2d Array which I try to **parallelize**. For doing so, I first split the indices of the array into **non-overlapping sets** so that processing the given index set becomes free of concurrent access to the same cell of the array, and hence can be processed in parallel with no loss of data. My array is 2d **shared array** and I use the **@distributed** macros to achieve parallelism in a loop. Namely,

I have a the following function

```
using Distributed
using SharedArrays

function compute(Z, reg)
# Z is a 2d Shared array, reg is an array of indices described above.

N = size(Z,1);

q = true;
while (q == true)
    q = false;

    for i = 1:length(reg)

        @distributed for j = 1:length(reg[i])
            # reg[i] is defined so that the cells of Z used in this loop do NOT intersect
            k = reg[i][j];
            if (Z[ k ] >= 4 )
                 q = true;
                 Z[k] -= 4;
                 Z[k + 1] += 1;
                 Z[k - 1] += 1;
                 Z[k + N] += 1;
                 Z[k - N] += 1;
            end
        end
        #println(typeof(Z));
    end
end

return Z;
end
```

This function, in its current form, produces a **wrong** result (see the data below), however, when I remove the comment on the **println(typoef(Z))**, the result becomes correct. The result is also **correct**, if I use a standard loop instead of the **@distributed** loop, so it's not the logic of my code which is flawed, but my use of shared arrays and @distributed loops.

> My question: Why does the **println** affect performance of the shared arrays?

I understand it's not specifically the **println** itself, but perhaps somehow the println forces all distributed loops to operate on the same copy of the array, while without it the arrays in each loop are separate copies of the original array.

I would appreciate any insights into this issue, and suggestions for correct use of shared arrays and distributed loops in such situations.

---

---

*What follows can be skipped*, it is the data on which the function above operates, and the results of the process.

This is a sample data in my array **Z**, before feeding to the function **compute**

```
0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  2  6  2  0  0
0  2  4  2  4  2  0
0  6  2  0  2  6  0
0  2  4  2  4  2  0
0  0  2  6  2  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

The of type the array is:

```
SharedArrays.SharedArray{UInt8,2}
```

These are the regions of indices I use (my array is 7x7, but I use linear indexing here)

```
9-element Array{Any,1}:
 Int32[1, 4, 7, 22, 25, 28, 43, 46, 49]
 Int32[8, 11, 14, 29, 32, 35]
 Int32[15, 18, 21, 36, 39, 42]
 Int32[2, 5, 23, 26, 44, 47]
 Int32[9, 12, 30, 33]
 Int32[16, 19, 37, 40]
 Int32[3, 6, 24, 27, 45, 48]
 Int32[10, 13, 31, 34]
 Int32[17, 20, 38, 41]
```

The result of **compute(Z, reg)** with #println off (*the wrong result*):

```
0  0  0  1  0  0  0
0  0  4  2  4  1  0
0  4  0  5  1  0  1
1  2  5  0  5  4  1
0  4  1  5  2  0  1
0  1  0  4  0  2  0
0  0  1  1  1  0  0
```

The result with **println** ON (*the correct result*)

```
 0  0  1  2  1  0  0
 0  2  2  2  2  2  0
 1  2  2  2  2  2  1
 2  2  2  0  2  2  2
 1  2  2  2  2  2  1
 0  2  2  2  2  2  0
 0  0  1  2  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

The `@distributed` macro does not wait for the workers to complete the computation in a `for` loop like that. It just kicks off the computations.  So that means your `i` loop could occur out of order if the `j` loop executions haven't completed yet — and it appears that the time to print is enough to prevent that from happening.

To fix this, just put a `@sync` in front of the distributed macro.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply (+1), adding @sync fixed the issue.